# MFC, Select, order by date, put inside CRecordSet

Tags: sql, oracle, mfc, recordset

I need to select rows from SQL, and put them inside CRecordSet.
The CRecordSet should hold them sorted by date.
Should i "order by date" on the SQL Query, or to sort them inside the CRecordSet, or maybe move to CArray of objects and sort the CArray ?

is it possible to sort with the SQL Query, when inserting them to the CRecordset the order will stay the same?

thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should "order by date" when selecting the recordset. That way they will be ordered that way in your CRecordsSet.

Sorting the CRecordset won't affect the order in the database. The rows are "ordered" by the keys. They don't have any (meaningful) order in the physical database. If you have a 'date' key, the ORDER BY DATE clause will (hopefully) run faster - since it can just use that key - otherwise it will sort them for you, and therefore be a bit slower. But either way the CRecordset will appear sorted.

There's no need for the records to "stay sorted" on disk because the indices and/or the ORDER BY clause will give you the records in any order you want at any time. Just say "ORDER BY DATE" every time you get the records and they will always appear to be ... well ... ordered by date ;-)

As far as moving to an array and sorting it, if at all possible you want the SQL database to do the work for you. If you can keep it on the server - which presumably has more memory, etc. - even better. There may be a very special case where you want to sort your records in memory locally, but this doesn't look like it.

Hope that helps.